# Datagridview Column width not changing

Tags: c#, datagridview

[this is the property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYFs3.png) | [this is the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9grBj.png)

i cant seem to resize my column width in Datagridview. Here is my code:

```
      public void dgvwidth()
    {
        crud.FillDataGrid("Select ProductID,BrandName,Dosage from ProductItems", ref dgvOrderproductlist);
        dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[0].Width = 80;
        dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[1].Width = 250;
        dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[2].Width = 80;
    }
      private void HomePage_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvwidth();
    }
```

I'm trying to get just 3 columns from my table and change it column width to fit my Datagridview. its not getting any error but its not changing the column width as well.

```
    public void FillDataGrid(string sql, ref DataGridView dg)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            cn.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            adptr = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adptr.Fill(ds);
            dg.DataSource = "";
            dg.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dg.AutoResizeColumns();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + e.Message);
        }
        cn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Look at the AutoSizeMode of the columns, most of the time the width is ignored and the AutoSizeMode determines the actual size.  (Set it to "None"), although you might be wanting to have 1 column be set to Fill if you're trying to have your columns actually fill the datagridview.

Comment: It is set to 'none' sir.

Comment: And the AutoSizeColumnsMode of the DataGridView is also set to none?

Comment: I thought you are already referring to AutoSizeColumnsMode which is set to none. Where can i find the AutoSizeMode of the columns?

Comment: dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode

Comment: "dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.None;" like this sir? i put it in my code still no use

Comment: Assuming the width of the datagridview is 80+80+250? Can you add a picture of what you're seeing?

Comment: I added the pic sir on top.

Comment: also added property

Comment: The error is on the event. you shouldnt do something like that on the load event. Somehow your code might get overrided

Comment: Then where should i put it sir? And there is no error. its just not resizing.

Comment: It's an "error" because is not resizing. anyway i would put it on form activated. just to be sure it gets done at the end of everything. [this](http://www.csharp411.com/c-winforms-form-event-order/) migth help

Comment: I put it in form activated and still not doing anything sir.

Comment: Can you add the relevant code from the Designer.cs file showing everything that is being set on the dgvOrderproductlist and all of the columns?

Comment: Can you show the FillDataGrid code? Perhaps you're doing something in there. A quick test on my end worked as expected and other than the dummy datasource, it's pretty much your same code.

Comment: @CharlesMay i added the code sir

Comment: ohhh i thinks its the autoresize from the method

Comment: Yea, I would remark out the AutoResizeColumns() in your FillDataGrid method and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: @CharlesMay  That solved the problem thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try like this

```
 public void dgvwidth()
{
    crud.FillDataGrid("Select ProductID,BrandName,Dosage from ProductItems", ref dgvOrderproductlist);

 var column = dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[0];
 column.Width = 80;

 column  = dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[1];
 column.Width = 250;
  column  =     dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[2];
  column.Width = dgvOrderproductlist.Width - dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[0].Width - dgvOrderproductlist.Columns[1].Width - 50;

 }
```

Comment: I am assuming AutoSize is set to none .

Comment: Yes sir its set to none. I tried your code still not doing anything with no errors.